# Machine learning algorithm to find similar or matching records?

Tags: python, machine-learning, levenshtein-distance, textmatching, matchmaking

I have a data-set which contains records/Configuration of a particular Laptop(Ex Ram,Hard disk). Now i want to create an algorithm that can  tell me which laptop/desktop in the current year is closest to that configuration.
I want to give 3 recommendation based based on the closest match?
Which ML algorithm should i use and whats the best way to approach ?

Comment: Typically you would want to define a "distance function" between records and use a clustering algorithm.

Comment: Why do you think you need machine learning for that task?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your data, you can use clustering. Kmeans is just an example. 
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

You can also use KNN classification by setting the number of neighbors as you want:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html